# ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit - Content Security Policy

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, content-security-policy

I've got an internal web application.  This is a webforms .net 4.x application.  It uses the ajax control toolkit along with the updatepanel.  Specifically, it uses the tabcontainer/tabpanels a lot.  I had a problem getting the tabcontainer/tabpanels to work until I opened up the csp.  I did that several years.  I have a content security policy setup in my web.config file:

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```

This csp allows for everything to work.  Now, I have two problems:

- The security folks have listed the current csp as a low risk security issue and would like me to change it.  It's low risk, but I would like to provide some type of solution to this if possible.  I've read several posts about how hard it is to get the ACT to work right with CSP, so it may not be possible.  I've tried to create a ACT bundle and just send that down, but I get an error message in the Chrome inspector saying that is a 404 iirc.  Everything works, but I don't like the 404 error.  Removing the bundle in the script manager seems to work and does not create any additional errors.  Has anyone else noticed a 404 error in google chrome inspect with an ACT bundle in the script manager?
- I have recently had to add two more tabs.  These two tabs have an iframe that displays content from another internal website.  to get this to work under the tabs, I have to actually remove the csp.  I don't think that they will like the removed csp.

I have tried to play with a csp to load some test content from google.  Unfortunately, the following csp does not work.  I would think it would load from the current local server and a google site.  Unfortunately, the content from google.com does not load.  Chrome gives me an unhappy face trying to load.  Suggestions are appreciated on how to only load content from the local server and a single remote server.

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-src 'self' *.google.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.google.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.google.com" />
```

So, the question (thanks pkalkins), how do I add the ability to include an iframe containing content from another internal site so that the iframe correctly displays content within that iframe?  I have used the google.com site as just an example that I test with here on my remote system.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions.  :-)

Wally

Comment: You may want to include a question... it's hard to know what to say really because we don't know whether you need high security, very low security, what risks you are trying to avoid/not avoid... just off the top of my head though, 'unsafe-eval', seems like a very bad idea.  Cross-site iframes, are a little less risky, but be sure to write cookies safely.  (http-only, same-site)

Comment: Thanks pcalkins.  I have added an actual question.  Its hard to remember to put everything in when you are doing a brain dump.  Regarding the unsafe-eval, we only have content locally, and I am checking all input and sanitizing it.  The tabs don't seem to work properly without it.

Comment: You can do that without using eval methods.

Comment: To answer your question, you shouldn't have any problems if the other internal site is in the same domain.

Comment: The same domain is what I thought as well, but I am running into issues with this.  I'm playing around with it.  I'm also playing around locally using localhost on development, which is probably what is causing my local development issue.  still working.  :-/

Comment: Well, it could have been a complete brain fart on my end, but things are working now.  I may have misremembered issues about the iframe not working because that web.config is now working.  thanks for your help @pcalkins.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is having an issue locking down the Ajax Control Toolkit, you can adjust settings in the ASP ScriptManager Control to affect change.

1.) You can select "release" for the ScriptMode property, the default setting is AUTO and this may be running your scripts in Debug mode depending on your retail mode settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptmode?view=netframework-4.8.1

2.) Set the AjaxFrameworkMode property to explicit, so that you are only using the Ajax functions you need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.ajaxframeworkmode?view=netframework-4.8.1

This has worked for me and I hope it can help you eliminate the need to use 'unsafe-eval'

Comment: I just tried the ajaxframeworkmode="Explicit" setting and it seems to turn off the script manager.  Am I missing something?  TIA

Comment: You would need to register your scripts... Please see the section on including your scripts. http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.net/ToolkitScriptManager/ToolkitScriptManager.aspx

Also, depending upon your situation, you might need to add a nonce for running inline scripts to your CSP header.

Comment: As a side note, I am not using the TabContainers or anything else in the AjaxToolkit, only regular Update Panels. I hope this works for you because this was a real pain for me as well.